# Filter df according to multiple conditions with dyplr in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a df structured like this:

```
  a.  b. 
  L.  1
  L.  2
  M.  3
  M.  2
```

"a" and "b" are columns names.

I want to filter the dataframe using dplyr. The conditions are: `if (a == L & b > 1)` **and at the same time** `if (a == M & b > 2)`

the result would be:

```
  a.  b. 
  L.  2
  M.  3
```

how can I do?
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
>tibble(a=c('L','L','M','M'),b=c(1:3,2)) %>%
+   dplyr::filter((a == 'L' & b > 1) | (a == 'M' & b > 2))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  a         b
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 L         2
#2 M         3
```